# Why does Go stdlib use a mutually exclusive lock to read context's error field?

Tags: go, locking, mutex, standard-library

There are a number of under-the-hood implementations of the `Context` interface in the Go standard library. For instance, the `Background` and `TODO` contexts are backed by the unexposed `emptyCtx` type which is essentially just `int` with some stub methods ([proof](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2aa473cc54128c1498f80263763a2a876308e565/src/context/context.go#L171-L218)). Similarly, every call to `context.WithCancel()` returns an instance of the `cancelCtx` type which is already a proper struct with a bunch of mutex-protected attributes ([proof](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/2aa473cc54128c1498f80263763a2a876308e565/src/context/context.go#L342-L349)):

```
// A cancelCtx can be canceled. When canceled, it also cancels any children
// that implement canceler.
type cancelCtx struct {
    Context

    mu       sync.Mutex            // protects following fields
    done     atomic.Value          // of chan struct{}, created lazily, closed by first cancel call
    children map[canceler]struct{} // set to nil by the first cancel call
    err      error                 // set to non-nil by the first cancel call
}
```

Why does the `cancelCtx` struct use a mutually exclusive lock and not an `RWLock`? For instance, the `Err()` method currently acquires a full lock while it (probably) could have used just an `RLock`:

```
func (c *cancelCtx) Err() error {
    c.mu.Lock()
    err := c.err
    c.mu.Unlock()
    return err
}
```

Comment: You'd have to ask the author's to know for sure (and you can, using [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts)), but a good guess is that because RWMutex is three(!) times the size of Mutex, and context values are ubiquitous, the read-to-write ratio in real programs would need to be much higher to be worth the trade-off. Now that I think about it, I'm not even convinced that reads are more frequent than writes to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason should be `RWLock` [has poor performance](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17973).

The performance of locks doesn't depends on the features it provides, it depends on the underlying `implementation`. Although theoretically `RWLock` can provides higher `throughputs`, for this specific scenario (mutating a tiny variable), `Mutex` could provide lower `unnecessary overhead`.